# Vulkan Dynamic Buffer With Different Texture Per Object

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I am currently using a dynamic buffer to store the uniforms of multiple objects and update them individually without changing the shader. The problem is that when i am adding a VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER to my descriptor the render is [this](https://stdntpartners-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/antonios_katopodis_studentpartner_com/EVgHodCa2nxJteJySvroQB4BYP8vkv8Tn9eW8QWpbbUkJQ?e=Pzn3Vz) (I can't post images due to low reputation)! Just the color of the background of the texture. This is my initialization of the descriptor().

```
descriptorWrites[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
    descriptorWrites[0].dstSet = descriptorSet;
    descriptorWrites[0].pNext = NULL;
    descriptorWrites[0].dstBinding = 0;
    descriptorWrites[0].dstArrayElement = 0;
    descriptorWrites[0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
    descriptorWrites[0].descriptorCount = 1;
    descriptorWrites[0].pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo;

    descriptorWrites[1].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
    descriptorWrites[1].dstSet = descriptorSet;
    descriptorWrites[1].pNext = NULL;
    descriptorWrites[1].dstBinding = 1;
    descriptorWrites[1].dstArrayElement = 0;
    descriptorWrites[1].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
    descriptorWrites[1].descriptorCount = 1;
    descriptorWrites[1].pImageInfo = &imageInfo;
```

And this is my fragment shader:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(set=0, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D texSampler;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 fragTexCoord;


layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = texture(texSampler, fragTexCoord*2);
}
```

What could be the reason of this? I have updated descriptor layout, and the validation layer don't throw any errors and the dynamic buffer was working perfectly even for multiple objects. Is the binding corrupted or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried changing the output color to be based on the texture coordinates instead of actually being loaded from the texture?  i.e. `outColor = vec4(fragTexCoord, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: Incorrectly uploaded texture coordinates or the texture data itself? Wrong input attribute description?

Comment: Hello, i've tried replacing it but now the screen is pure black. I thinks it a problem with the dynamic buffer. I am binding the descriptor like this: `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 1, &dynamicOffset);`
)

Comment: If UV (as color) is black I doubt the descriptor sets are the problem. Check if your vertex layout matches the vertex buffer elements and the inputs of the VS and also if the VS properly forwards UV to the FS.

Comment: What are you using `dynamicOffset` for. Also, just render the tex coords into the rgb channels first to convince yourself that the UV mapping is done correctly.